# How to add data to (wenzhixin) bootstrap-table?

Tags: bootstrap-4

I need to add data to wenzhixin bootstrap-table after table is initialized. For example, here is JS I call on button click:

```
    function   addData(){
      var data = 
      [
        {
            "id": 1,
            "name": "test1",
            "price": "$0"
        },
        {
            "id": 2,
            "name": "test2",
            "price": "$20"
        }
      ];
      $('#table').bootstrapTable({
        data: data
      });
    }
```

but data is not populated on table. Why not?
thank you

Comment: Could you post all your code in the html file?

Comment: I have jsfiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/k4xe05d8/1/ thank you.

Answer (score 0):

solution is

```
$('#table').bootstrapTable('load', data);
```

and not

```
$('#table').bootstrapTable({
  data: data
});
```